# Is thin gem compatible with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

while migrating to rails 3 i need to know what gem version of thin gem wil be compatible with rails 3

Comment: Why don't you just install the latest version?

Comment: well i am migrating the rails from 2.3.11 to 3.0.0 so i need to know all this things instead of testing every gem :)

Comment: ..just add `gem 'thin'` in your Gemfile and do a `bundle install`. The latest version of this is compatible with Rails 3. You should upgrade to Rails 3.0.7 (latest).

Comment: ok i wil. one thing more can you suggest me any website from where i can get information about all the gems and there compatibility with Rails versions?

Answer (score 1):

If your using bundle, just add

```
gem "thin"
```

to you Gemfile and run `bundle install`.

By the way, I use thin version 1.4.1 with rails 3.